Creating a new attack class for Royal Janissary in AOE2
I'm kinda at the end of the way looking for a miracle.
In the AOE2 scenario editor, I'm trying to create a custom Royal Janissary that does bonus damage to cavalry units with the trigger effect named "Modify attribute." However, due to some weird rule stated by Microsoft devs, if the unit doesn't have the attack class in the first place you can't directly modify it and you need to create the attack class.
However, no information, no post and NO GUIDE has been provided to explain how to create this new attack class, and of course the modify attribute trigger effect doesn't have this option or at least it's not clearly shown.



Here's the guide I've been using so far: Link to the armor class guide
Modify attribute guide and explanation
Can someone help me please?
From the Beijing forum, it appears I must use the Create attack trigger, but this doesn’t work.

@Maslie Your question seems fine and on-topic to me. You may start a discussion on [meta] if you want to seek feedback or discuss your question with the community.

Can you explain what you mean when you say that the Create Attack trigger doesn't work at all? Do you get an error? What are the steps you are taking to create it?

I don't get an error it just that the unit doesn't get the damage bonus although I'm looking at something called XS scripting but the langage as a lot of bugs and none working function for some reason

This is information I've found online at a few places, I haven't tested it fully myself; it's from the forum here: Giving attack bonus to a unit and here: Advanced Genie Editor (AGE).
I think you'll need to add the attack class using Advanced Genie Editor. That programme should have come with DE; it'll be in the Tools_Builds folder of wherever you have the game installed, for me it's:

Make sure you take a backup of your data files first; rather than modding the main game files, you'll want to mod a copy of them.
When you open AGE, you'll need to Open the data files. Choose Age of Empires II Definitive Edition, then if you need to change the default directory enter in the "Custom path override" box and click on Age of Empires II Definitive Edition again, then click Open.
You can now find the Janissary Unit (or whatever else you want to modify) in the units list, and add the Attack Class 8 to it.
Then when you click save, don't override the main game files; instead, change the location to file path "C:\Users<yourname>\Games\Age of Empires 2 DE\mods\local<Your Mod Name here>\resources_common\dat" and save a new dat file, which you can load when doing a custom game. That second forum link notes that if you're using Rise of Rome the folder locations might be different:

I’d guess that the file path you want is “C:\Users[JSmith]\Games\Age of Empires 2 DE[A large number]\mods\local[Your Mod Name here]\modes\Pompeii\resources_common\dat” for the mod, and “C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\AoE2DE\modes\Pompeii\resources_common\dat” for the DAT file to copy off.


The only issue is Genie editor doesn't modify a single scenario it modify the whole game and is used for modding, it's a very good tool but not for my case
